# Почему программа на Java работает неправильно?

Tags: java

Я написал простенькую программу, которая должна просить ввести 1 символ, пока не будет введена точка. Если точка введена, то отображается количество нажатий Enter (то есть количество попыток для того, чтобы угадать символ). Если пользователь вводит "q", то программа завершает свою работу.

```
import java.util.Scanner;     
class Main {
        public static void main(String args[])
      throws java.io.IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            char choice;
            int count = 0;

            do {
                System.out.print("Введите любой символ: ");
                choice = scanner.next().charAt(0);
                System.out.println();
                count++;
            } while (choice != '.' && choice != 'q');

            switch(choice) {
                case '.':
                    System.out.println("Вы нажали Enter " + count + " раз.");
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

При выполнении программа работает неправильно, запрашивая по три раза ввод символа. До сих пор не могу понять в чем дело.

```
C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\Point>java Point
Введите любой символ: f

Введите любой символ:
Введите любой символ:
Введите любой символ: h

Введите любой символ:
Введите любой символ:
Введите любой символ: k

Введите любой символ:
Введите любой символ:
Введите любой символ: .

Вы нажали Enter 10 раз.

C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\Point>
```

Comment: почему-то у меня все норм. Свитч делать смысла не нет ибо проверка на `q` ничего не делает. с тем же успехом можно проверить на точку `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё корректно у меня работает. Перезагрузите компьютер, нажмите `Build ->Rebuild project`. Вот лог:

```
Введите любой символ: h

Введите любой символ: h

Введите любой символ: d

Введите любой символ: j

Введите любой символ: t

Введите любой символ: r

Введите любой символ: e

Введите любой символ: y

Введите любой символ: r
```

Попробуйте [онлайн компилятор java](https://www.compilejava.net/)

Comment: Перезагрузите компьютер? зачем?

Comment: UPD. Если на уровне он-лайн компилятора у вас тоже самое, ищите проблему в аппаратном обеспечении, может у вас клава заела. У меня в моей карьере случались аппаратные ошибки там, где их быть не должно, а мы искали программные.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor я работаю в т.ч. и с микроконтроллерами, мой богатый опыт показывает, что аппаратные ошибки в программах случаются.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, большое спасибо. Решилась проблема.